# "Path contains empy part" when I am trying to connect my DB info to my pin.Setbinding/Bindingcontext

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
foreach (var currentItem in getInfo["results"]) {

            theName = currentItem ["name"].ToString ();

            var pin = new Pin ();
            pin.Label = "test";
            pin.Adress = "test2";
            pin.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding (theName)); 
            pin.BindingContext = theName;
            //this (setbinding, bindingcontext) gives me the error, if I add the value from the DB (theName) on my pin.Label instead it works fine. So the problem is when i am doing this setbinding/bindingcontext thing here.

}
```

I get the value of "theName" that is a string in my log but it crashes when I try to bind it to the setbinding/bindingcontext. The error says: "Path contains empy part". If i bind it to my pin.Adress or pin.Adress it works fine. And if i Type "test" on my setbinding/bindingcontext it works as well. So i am very confused about what is wrong.

This is how i reach my data (it works):

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
{
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

    var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("localhost");

    var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

    var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

    return jsonResult;

}
```

Comment: You can't use `theName` in the `SetBinding` call and as the `BindingContext`. The parameters to `SetBinding` are: the property and the path to the property in the `BindingContext` object. I am also not sure that you can use the `Label.TextProperty` as a binding on a `Pin`. You can read more about bindings in Xamarin.Forms here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#C

Comment: It has worked before though when I gathered data the same way I am now. I used parse at the time when it worked i think. And i recieved the data via a httprequest as well so the exact code is the same.

Comment: What have you changed between the time it worked and now? What was the value of `theName` when it worked and what is the value now? It's possible that it was working because the value of `theName` just happened to work for the binding, and now a different value does not work for the binding (when using `SetBinding` incorrectly).

Comment: Now i use longer sentences. That is the difference.But for example if i type:     `pin.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("test this now"));
        pin.BindingContext = "is this working or not";` the code runs very well which is very strange because theName is a string containing text. So i dont get it why it isnt working?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that "pin.Label = theName;" won't do?

Comment: I use the setbinding/bindingcontext to get a value that is not shown, so that i can use it as a filter via a searchbar (like you helped me with). Can the issue be that the text contains "."/dots? I think I had an encounter with that before. Just a thought

Comment: If you just want to stuff an extra piece of data in the BindingContext, there's no need to use SetBinding.

Comment: That small thing did it. It didnt like that i was using setbinding i guess. Thanks. I will upvote you if you decide to type an answer.